# Capturing a specific window using C++ returns old data

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, winapi, screen-capture

I'm currently working on a project that requires to take a screenshot a specific window.
That's what I got so far:

**Main function**

```
int main() {
    
    LPCSTR windowname = "Calculator";
    HWND handle = FindWindowA(NULL, windowname);
    
    while (!handle) {
        std::cout << "Process not found..." << std::endl;
        handle = FindWindowA(NULL, windowname);
        Sleep(100);
    }
    
    Mat img = captureScreenMat(handle);
    resetMat();
    imwrite("test2.jpg", img);
    showInMovedWindow("IMG", img);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    
   
    return 0;

}
```

**winCapture**

```
Mat src;

void showInMovedWindow(string winname, Mat img) {
    namedWindow(winname);
    moveWindow(winname, 40, 30);
    imshow(winname, img);
}


BITMAPINFOHEADER createBitmapHeader(int width, int height)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    return bi;
}
int getHeight(HWND hwnd) {
    
RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    return height;
    
}

int getWidth(HWND hwnd) {
    
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    return width;
    
}
Mat captureScreenMat(HWND hwnd)
{


    HDC hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
  
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    int screenx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int screeny = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int width = getWidth(hwnd);
    int height = getHeight(hwnd);

    src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);
    HBITMAP hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = createBitmapHeader(width, height);

    
    //DEBUG
    cout << hbwindow << endl;
    cout << hwindowCompatibleDC << endl;
    cout << hwindowDC << endl;


    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);

    StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, screenx, screeny, width, height, SRCCOPY);  
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);            


    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    DeleteDC(hwindowDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}

void resetMat() {

    src.release();

}
```

Most windows work really well with this approach, but there are some windows that are working the first time, I try to take a img of them, but every time I try to take another screenshot of the same process, it just gives me the first screenshot I took of it. It only works again after a restart of the process and even then It just works again for one screenshot and all after are the same.
I thought it would be some kind of memory leak, but I'm deleting all the objects and releasing the handle.
I think that something is wrong with the handle, but I couldn't figure out what.
I'm not familiar with working with the windowsAPI and hope someone knowns more than me.

Fixed: Process blocked creating handle.

Comment: remove all usage of OpenCV in the acquisition phase. is the problem remains, you at least know it's not OpenCV. use statically allocated C arrays for the data, then wrap in a cv::Mat (data pointer, CV_8UC4, height, width) for imshow. that way, there's no way OpenCV allocation/deallocation can affect the data.

Comment: The system already provides a [screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) implementation you can use.

Comment: Can the [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image#code-example) example work for you?

Comment: Try getting rid of that global variable or at least make sure that you really create new memory by returnig src.clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `SelectObject` you must save the previous-selected handle (available from the return value) and you MUST select it back before deleting or releasing the device context.

Right now you are breaking a bunch of rules.

1. Deleting a bitmap which is selected into a device context.
2. Deleting a DC gotten from `GetDC`.
3. Calling both `DeleteDC` and `ReleaseDC` on the same handle.
4. Passing `NULL` as the first parameter of `ReleaseDC`, which should be the same `HWND` passed to `GetDC`.
5. Deleting a DC without selecting the original bitmap back into it.

These bugs royally mess up the window DC.  If it was a transient DC, the system probably cleans up your mess immediately.  But if the window class has the `CS_OWNDC` or `CS_CLASSDC` flags, you do permanent damage to the window.  That's why your method appears to work with some windows and not others.